# What are ld response files?

Tags: c++, linker, ld, clang++

I have fairly long `clang++` compilation command (generated) and I'm trying to debug an error. The command links weakly to a number of libraries, including my library. So somewhere in the command there's this:

```
... -weak_library "path-to-lib1" -weak_library "path-to-lib2" -weak_library "path-to-mylib" -rpath "some-path" ...
```

The command fails with the error:

```
ld: file not found: -rpath
```

Now, if I remove `-weak_library "path-to-mylib"` completely or copy "mylib" somewhere else and provide new path, compilation succeeds. This does not make sense to me.

After passing `-v`, I see this output:

```
...
Arguments passed via response file: "path-to-mylib"
(end of response file)
ld: file not found: -rpath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

AND the command omits "path-to-mylib" argument completely, leaving just `... -weak_library -rpath ...` which generates the error above.

I couldn't find any official information on what response files are in clang. What are they used for and why my library is being treated like one by `ld`?

Comment: from `ld`'s man page 

`@response_file_path  Inserts contents of file at response_file_path into arguments. This allows for linker command line args to be store in a file.  Note: ld is normally invoked through clang, and clang also interprets @file on the command line.  To have clang ignore the @file and pass it through to ld, use -Wl,@file.`